# KnockoutJS Which Model does the Minicart use?

Tags: magento2, template, model, knockoutjs, mini-cart

So, i'm very new when it comes to using KnockoutJS but i've been doing some reading around it and to my knowledge each template file has its own corresponding model.

However, as i'm looking through the template file located at:

> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

I cannot find any reference to the model it is linked to. My goal is to add an afterAdd function to the foreach contained within the following code block:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
<dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
<dd class="values">
    <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
        <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
        <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</dd>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This should then call the corresponding afterAdd function within the model and I can run some code. But after looking through the models located within:

> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model

i'm having no luck finding it.

**Update:**

It is possible that I have found the corresponding file under:

> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

However, adding a callback function so that I can run some code in this file is still an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Now you can able to see how the minicart renders and how it binds with knockoutjs. Check the following code snippet.

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
</item>
```

This is your template:

> Magento_Checkout/minicart/content

Corresponding js

> Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart

Now open

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

Check the following code snippet on how to render the item

```
<if args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
    <strong class="subtitle" translate="'Recently added item(s)'"/>
    <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
        <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartItems(), as: 'item' }">
            <each args="$parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type))"
                  render="{name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}}"
            />
        </ol>
    </div>
</if>
```

**$parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)** this is actually retrun **defaultRenderer** from the **Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart** class.

**How?**

Open
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml**

Here, define the item template and render.

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
        <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
        <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

So **$parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type))** now looks like:

> $parent.getRegion(defaultRenderer)

If you check **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml**

```
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/item/default</item>
        </item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="item.image" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/image</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/product/image</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">itemImage</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Check this line

```
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
```

Product item comes **vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php**

Inside **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html** you can access all.

If you want to add js, then overwrite **Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart** and added here. You can access that method using $parent from template.

Comment: Brilliant answer and well explained! Thanks for the help Sohel - A

Comment: Alright so I have been playing around with this a little bit but I cant seem to get the callback function to work correctly. I have changed ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } to ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option', afterRender: updateBundle }. Where abouts in the minicart.js file do I place this callback function as it keeps saying its undefined

Comment: Use $parents[1]. updateBundle, something like that.

Comment: You're a star. Up and working now as expected! It took a while to get my head around it but you've helped a lot. Cheers - A

Comment: Great. Happy to help :)